# How can I check that I am in the build_phase in the UVM?

Tags: uvm

I would like to create a function that can only be called during the build_phase().  (Calls during other phases should generate a fatal error.)

How do I find out what uvm_phase I am in?

Answer (score 4):

The *phase that you are in* is represented by the phase argument of the *_phase method. There is no single state that represents the current state, because the UVM has many possible phase domains that could be simultaneously active. So you will have to either pass the phase into the function when calling it:

```
function void my_function(uvm_phase phase);
  if (!phase.is(uvm_build_phase::get()) `uvm_fatal(...);
endfunction
```

Or if this function is a method of a class derived from uvm_component, you can override the phase_started method

```
class my_component extends uvm_component;

protected uvm_phase m_current_phase
function void phase_started(uvm_phase phase);
  super.phase_started(phase);
  m_current_phase = phase;
endfunction : phase_started

  function void my_function(..);
      if (!m_current_phase.is(uvm_build_phase::get()) `uvm_fatal(...);
  endfunction
```

Comment: What you said about multiple domains only applies to the run phase. There is only one build phase shared by all components.

Answer (score 1):

There's a field in `uvm_component` called `m_current_phase`, that contains the most recently executed phase. The field isn't technically part of the standard API, but the comment shows that the developers are considering adding an accessor for it:

```
class test extends uvm_test;
  function void print_cur_phase();
    m_current_phase.print();
  endfunction // print_cur_phase

  function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    print_cur_phase();
  endfunction // build_phase

  task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    print_cur_phase();
  endtask

  // ...
endclass
```

The most portable way of doing it is to define your own variable like Dave showed in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how uvm_component::new checks that components are not created after build_phase is done (error messages stripped):

```
begin
  uvm_phase bld;
  uvm_domain common;
  common = uvm_domain::get_common_domain();
  bld = common.find(uvm_build_phase::get());
  if (bld == null)
    uvm_report_fatal(...);
  if (bld.get_state() == UVM_PHASE_DONE) begin
    uvm_report_fatal(...);
  end
end
```

This uses the singleton getters for the common domain and uvm_build_phase, so you do not need to manually track any phase starts/states locally, and can just inspect these when your function is called.

Comment: Can you give some example code for using this?